# Series about an enhanced man on the run from enhanced agents

Tags: story-identification

Back in the 70's I read a series of books featuring an enhanced man that was on the run from mysterious greatly enhanced agents. the enhancement was via implants for the hero whereas the agents had cybernetic augmentation of the skeleton and musculoskeletal system hence their greater power. the hero and the agents were created by the same agency and his augmentation may have been a development stage.

When the hero was near an enhanced he could power up using their energy against them. One example was pushing an enhanced out of a tower block window and riding the agent down to the ground where the agent's legs pistoned through his torso, but the hero was alive.

Anyone?

Comment: Where did you read this? Were they enhanced cybernetically or via other means? Any other plot point you can remember? Take a look at [this list](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and see if you can [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: @Gallifreyan, Stolen my stock answer :(

Comment: @Edlothiad there's a reason they call it [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533/348200)

Answer (score 3):

This is the 'Hook' series by Kenneth Buulmer.
*[Hook](https://www.goodreads.com/series/149021-hook)* (under pseudonym Tully Zetford)

1. Whirlpool of Stars (1974)
2. The Boosted Man (1974)
3. Star City (1974)
4. The Virility Gene (1975)

From [a review of the first book](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/664657040?book_show_action=true):

[image: Whirlpool of Stars]

> Whirlpool of Stars opens with a starship breaking down – something in the engineroom blows up as a result of shoddy maintenance. The passengers and crew are forced to flee in lifeboats, though this is no orderly evacuation. Hook is aboard, and he manages to get a seat aboard one of the lifeboats. The nearest planet, however, is run by a rival corporation to that which had operated the starship, and everyone who lands would be subject high fees… which they can pay off by indentured labour… Hook evades the authorities and, with a woman in tow, runs about the planet, trying to **avoid slavery and also the Boosted Men, who are after him**.

....

> Hook is an alpha-male protagonist, but one with a weakness – **he is a Boosted Man himself, but an early iteration and his powers only operate when he is close proximity to a real Boosted Man**.

Comment: I second that. The main character Ryder Hook was used as prototype for the Novamen and gains full enhancement only when near a Novaman.

Comment: Also there is a scene where Ryder Hook uses the last Novaman on the planet to survie a fall, killing his opponent at the same time, as described by the OP.  Note that Tully Zetford is one of the many pen names of [Kenneth Bulmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Bulmer#Ryder_Hook_series_.28written_as_Tully_Zetford.29)

Comment: Splendid! that's the fellow. jolly decent of you to assist

Comment: just ordered. needed to scratch an itch. cheers

Comment: @harjindarpotterji If this is the correct answer, please *accept* it by clicking the checkmark on the left-hand side.